# Behavior of function "identical" with factors

Tags: r

R stores factors as integers. Therefore, when using the function identical, it cannot find when two factors are of the same name if they have different levels.

Here's an MWE:

```
y <- structure(list(portfolio_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("2000-10-31", "2001-04-30"), class = "factor"), 
security = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Currency Australia (Fwd)", 
"Currency Euro (Fwd)", "Currency Japan (Fwd)", "Currency United Kingdom (Fwd)"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("portfolio_date", "security"
), row.names = c(10414L, 10417L, 10424L, 21770L, 21771L, 21774L
), class = "data.frame")

x <- structure(list(portfolio_date = structure(1L, .Label = "2000-10-31", class = "factor"), 
security = structure(1L, .Label = "Currency Euro (Fwd)", class = "factor")),
 .Names = c("portfolio_date", "security"), row.names = 10414L, class = "data.frame")

identical(y[1,], x)
```

Returns `FALSE`

But if we look at the objects, they appear identical to the user

```
y[1,]
portfolio_date            security
10414     2000-10-31 Currency Euro (Fwd)

x
portfolio_date            security
10414     2000-10-31 Currency Euro (Fwd)
```

Ultimately I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
apply(y, 1, identical, x)
10414 10417 10424 21770 21771 21774 
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
which(apply(y, 1, identical, x))
1 2
```

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `identical(droplevels(y[1,]), droplevels(x))` or perhaps `all.equal(y[1,], x, check.attributes=F)`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but using droplevels in identical still returns FALSE. Further, apply(y, 1, function(z) all.equal(z, x, check.attributes=F)) has some strange output.

Comment: You'll have to convert the columns into characters.  Here is a solution in one line with base R: apply(apply(y, 2, as.character), 1, identical, apply(x, 2, as.character))

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e , can you list it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: `identical(droplevels(y[1,]), droplevels(x))` returns TRUE. please check again :)

Comment: @lebatsnok, my mistake, it does, just cannot vectorize nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform the comparison, the factors need to be converted into character objects.
By using base R alone here is a solution:

```
apply(apply(y, 2, as.character), 1, identical, apply(x, 2, as.character))
```

The inner apply loops convert each column in the source and target data frames to character objects and the outer apply loops through the rows.
If the x data frame has more than one row, the actual behavior may not be as expected.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the `rowwise` from `dplyr` to check row-by-row; If you need to compare the row.names at the same time then you need to create an `id` column for both, otherwise, it will return `TRUE` for the first two rows.

```
library(dplyr)
x$id <- row.names(x)
y$id <- row.names(y)
rowwise(y) %>% do(check = isTRUE(all.equal(., x, check.attributes = F))) %>% data.frame

  check
1  TRUE
2 FALSE
3 FALSE
4 FALSE
5 FALSE
6 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the package 'compare'.

```
library(compare)
result <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(y)){ 
one <- compare(y[i,], x, dropLevels=T)
two <- one$detailedResult[1]==T & one$detailedResult[2]==T
result <- c(result, two)
}
as.character(result)#TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for data posted in OP**

The example posted in the OP can be easily treated by using `droplevels()`.

Let us first look at why the comparison `identical(y[1,], x)` returns `FALSE`:

```
str(y[1,]) 
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:  
#$ portfolio_date: Factor w/ 2 levels "2000-10-31","2001-04-30": 1  
#$ security      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Currency Australia (Fwd)",..: 2
```

whereas

```
str(x)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ portfolio_date: Factor w/ 1 level "2000-10-31": 1
#$ security      : Factor w/ 1 level "Currency Euro (Fwd)": 1
```

So the difference lies in the factors, even though both objects are displayed in the same way, as shown in the OP's question.

This is where the function `droplevels()` is useful: it removes unused factors. By applying `droplevels()` to `y[1,]` with its redundant factors, we obtain:

> ```
> identical(droplevels(y[1,]), x)
> #[1] TRUE
> ```

If `x` also contains unused factors, it will be necessary to wrap it into `droplevels()`, too. In any case, it won't do any harm:

```
identical(droplevels(y[1,]), droplevels(x))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

**General solution**

Using `droplevels()` may not work if the real data is more complex than the data posted in the "MWE" of the OP. Such situations may include, e.g., equivalent entries in `x` and `y[1,]` that are stored as different factor levels. An example where `droplevels()` fails is given in the **data** section at the end of this answer.

The following solution represents an efficient possibility to treat such general situations. It works for the data posted in the OP as well as for the more complicated case of the data posted below.

First, two auxiliary vectors are created that contain only the characters of each row. By using `paste()` we can concatenate each row to a single character string:

```
temp_x <- apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=",")
temp_y <- apply(y, 1, paste, collapse=",")
```

With these vectors it becomes easily possible to compare rows of the original data.frames, even if the entries were originally stored as factors with different levels and numbering.

To identify which rows are identical, we can use the `%in%` operator, which is more appropriate than the function `identical()` in this case, as the former checks for equality of all possible row combinations, and not just individual pairs.

With these simple modifications the desired output can be obtained quickly and without further loops:

> ```
> setNames(temp_y %in% temp_x, names(temp_y))
> #10414 10417 10424 21770 21771 21774 
> # TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
> which(temp_y %in% temp_x)
> #[1] 1 2
> y[temp_y %in% temp_x,]
> #      portfolio_date            security
> #10414     2000-10-31 Currency Euro (Fwd)
> #10417     2000-10-31 Currency Euro (Fwd)
> ```

**data**

```
x <- structure(list(portfolio_date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2000-05-15", 
             "2000-10-31"), class = "factor"), security = structure(c(2L, 1L), 
             .Label = c("Currency Euro (Fwd)", "Currency USD (Fwd)"), 
             class = "factor")), .Names = c("portfolio_date", "security"), 
             class = "data.frame", row.names = c("10234", "10414"))

y <- structure(list(portfolio_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
              .Label = c("2000-10-31", "2001-04-30"), class = "factor"), 
              security = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
              .Label = c("Currency Australia (Fwd)", "Currency Euro (Fwd)", 
              "Currency Japan (Fwd)", "Currency United Kingdom (Fwd)"), 
              class = "factor")), .Names = c("portfolio_date", "security"), 
              row.names = c(10414L, 10417L, 10424L, 21770L, 21771L, 21774L), 
              class = "data.frame")
```